# executing alias on variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I came upon this strange behaviour in my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
V=a
alias $V="echo test"
echo $(a)                 #returns 'test'
echo $($V)                #returns ...'a: not found'
```

Is there any way to emulate the former behaviour with the variable?

Comment: What OS and `bash` version are you doing this with?  I get errors on both `echo` lines on Debian Jessie with bash 4.3.3.30

Comment: @StephenHarris yes you get error on both lines. What the author wants is why a variable cannot be like an alias and execute the command.

Comment: @FarazX The  comments in the original say he did _not_ get an error in both lines; in his case the alias was defined; in my case it wasn't.  Now with `ksh93` I get the results he gets, so the evaluation is definitely shell and version dependent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aliases are only expanded if the command appears directly in the code, without any expansion. Writing things like `\a`, `$V`, `$(echo a)`, etc. suppresses alias lookup.

In addition, bash (unlike other shells) doesn't expand aliases in scripts by default anyway, so `a` actually does *not* run the alias in bash.

Use a function instead of an alias. You'll need to use the original name to define the function.

```
V=a
a () { echo test; }
"$V"     # prints test
```

(There are other ways to do something like what you want by using `eval`, but don't use `eval` unless you know exactly what you're doing. Quoting things correctly with `eval` is tricky.)

Answer (score 2):

It like you're saying:

```
#!/bin/bash
V=a
alias $V="echo test"
echo `a`              #echo the out put of the 'echo test' command which is test 
echo `$V`             #echo the output of $V 'command' which is holding a value itself and it won't be executed as an alias since it's not used directly.
```

**EDIT**: Sorry I was wrong about saying that variables cannot be executed as command.

If a variable was the command itself, it could be executed, but not when its value is used as an alias. In that case, the value as an alias can work individually, since it's like you've set an alise.
But an alias cannot be passed from a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your insight; however, I am still confused as to how to obtain the desired behaviour.  How can I interpret the variable as if it were the command?

Comment: @ColeC What do you exactly want as your result?

Comment: I want to execute the string stored in the variable as if it were the command.

Comment: I have resolved my problem with the use of eval, which evaluates a string as a command.

Comment: Hmm... `filter='cat'` followed by `$filter file` will cat the file, so you _can_ use a variable as a command, it's just awkward to type on the command line.  In a script it's a real option.  Conditionally setting `$filter` to either `cat` or `gzip` makes switching a pipeline that puts `$filter >$output` at the end between compressing or not compressing a breeze.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I was wrong. Thanks for teaching me a new thing.

Comment: Variables don't "execute" commands.  All they do is get expanded as part of the steps the shell does while processing a line.  [The manual explains the steps the shell takes, in order](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation).  Since alias-expansion happens before variable-expansion, it doesn't happen on the values of variables.  But function lookup happens nearly last, after variable expansion, so you don't need an `eval` to run a command-name stored in a variable.